# Changing Hyperlink text in VB code for Gridview

Tags: vb.net, gridview

In the VB code below, I'm trying to set the Hyperlink hypNote's text as "Add Note" when text is null. However it is not working. As a test, I've even set the Hyperlink text as "Test" and tried:

```
If hypNote.text = "Test" Then
    hypNote.text = "Add Note"
End If
```

But still it doesn't work. Here's my code..

```
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server">
            <asp:Image ID="LiveOrders"  alt="Live Gif" runat="server" class="extrasButton" ImageUrl="~/files/images/liveOrders.gif" />
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DSOrders" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT tblOrders.OrderID, tblOrders.stallmessage, tblOrders.price, tblAccounts.city, tblAccounts.postcode, tblOrders.phoneNo, tblOrders.tblNo, tblOrders.info, tblOrders.orderDate, tblOrders.orderStatus, tblOrders.type, tblOrders.timeFor, tblOrders.paid, tblOrders.tblNo
            FROM tblOrders INNER JOIN tblAccounts ON tblOrders.accountID = tblAccounts.AccountID
            WHERE tblOrders.orderStatus='Completed'

            ORDER BY tblOrders.timeFor ASC">
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:GridView ID="gdvOrders" width="100%" runat="server" style="font-size:1.5em" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EmptyDataText="No orders" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGrid" DataKeyNames="orderID" DataSourceID="DSOrders" PageSize="20" AllowSorting="True">
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
                <Columns>  
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Order">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("stallMessage") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="price" HeaderText="Price" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="phoneNo" HeaderText="Phone No" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address/Table No.">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("tblNo") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-ForeColor="Red" HeaderText="Note">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="hypNote" style="Font-Size:20px; color:Red;" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "~/editNote.aspx?note=" & Eval("info").ToString & "&orderID=" & Eval("orderID").ToString %>' ><%# Eval("info") %></asp:HyperLink>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="type" HeaderText="Type" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="orderDate" DataFormatString="{0: H:mm:ss}" HeaderText="Order Time" SortExpression="orderDate" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="timeFor" DataFormatString="{0: H:mm:ss}" HeaderText="Time For" SortExpression="timeFor" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="paid" HeaderText="Paid" />

                        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="True">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton visible="true" ID="lnkSent" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
                                    onclientclick="return confirm('Mark As Sent?');" 
                                    ImageUrl="~/files/images/icons/sendIcon.png" onclick="lnkSent_Click"></asp:ImageButton>
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidnOrderID" runat="server"  Value='<%# Eval("orderID") %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </asp:Panel>

  Protected Sub gdvOrders_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gdvOrders.RowDataBound
    For Each r As GridViewRow in gdvOrders.Rows
        If r.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim hypNote As Hyperlink
            hypNote = r.Cells(4).FindControl("hypNote")
            If hypNote.text = "" Then
                hypNote.text = "Add Note"
            End If
        End If
    Next r
  End Sub
```

Additionally, I wish to change the text color of the Hyperlink when "Add Note" is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my mistake. I changed this line to:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hypNote" style="Font-Size:20px; color:Red;" text='<%# Eval("info") %>' runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "~/editNote.aspx?note=" & Eval("info").ToString & "&orderID=" & Eval("orderID").ToString %>' ></asp:HyperLink>
```

I didn't have text= in there.
All worked fine then.